# How to show simple summing with tex

Tags: mathtools, underbrace

[image]

I want to show simple summing like in the picture, without using colors. But I've no idea, that's not a undercase command.

Comment: You can use mathtools package that have these specific braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tikzmark`. Note that you must compile the document twice.

[image]

Define a new command `\nub` (nested under-bracket). The usage is `\nub{<level>}{<content>}`.

The levels must be non-repeating integers, and must range from 1 to the number of brackets. The brackets will cross if they are out of order. Spacing between brackets is controlled globally by `\unitht`, currently set to `.8ex`.

If you use more than one `nub` sequence in the document, each sequence must have its own "prefix". As stated in the screenshot, you must redefine `\nubpre` using `\renewcommand{\nubpre}{<prefix>}`.

Here is the code for the screenshot above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\unitht}{.8ex}
\newcommand{\nubpre}{A}

\newcommand{\nub}[2]{\tikzmark{a\nubpre#1}#2\tikzmark{b\nubpre#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1) --++(0,-#1*\unitht) -| (pic cs:b\nubpre#1);
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{\unitht}%
}

\begin{document}

\[\nub{5}{11+\nub{4}{12+\nub{3}{13+\nub{2}{14+\nub{1}{15+16}+17}+18}+19}+20}=31\times5=155.\]
You must choose a different nub prefix for each subsequent use
\renewcommand{\nubpre}{B}
\[\nub{3}{1+\nub{2}{2+\nub{1}{3+\cdots+98}+99}+100}=101\times50=5050.\]
using \verb`\renewcommand{\nubpre}{<prefix>}`. The default prefix is \verb`A`.

\end{document}
```