Make a file "standalonisable"
The following code compiled correctly.
% Source.
%     + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655445/6880

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\unitht}{.8ex}
\newcommand{\nubpre}{A}

\newcommand{\nub}[2]{
  \tikzmark{a\nubpre#1}#2\tikzmark{b\nubpre#1}
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
                      overlay]
    \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1)  % Trait vertical à partir
          --++ (0,-#1*\unitht) % de la marque droite.
          -|                   % TikZ va tracer un "L"
          (pic cs:b\nubpre#1); % jusqu'à la marque de gauche.
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace{\unitht}%
}

\begin{document}
$%
  \nub{3}{%
    1 + \nub{2}{%
      3 + \nub{1}{%
        5 + \cdots + %
        95} + %
      97} + %
    99}%
  = 100 \times 49 \div 2%
  = 245%
$

\end{document}

The following note doesn't compile. Why?
% Source.
%     + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655445/6880

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\unitht}{.8ex}
\newcommand{\nubpre}{A}

\newcommand{\nub}[2]{
  \tikzmark{a\nubpre#1}#2\tikzmark{b\nubpre#1}
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
                      overlay]
    \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1)  % Trait vertical à partir
          --++ (0,-#1*\unitht) % de la marque droite.
          -|                   % TikZ va tracer un "L"
          (pic cs:b\nubpre#1); % jusqu'à la marque de gauche.
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace{\unitht}%
}

\begin{document}
$%
  \nub{3}{%
    1 + \nub{2}{%
      3 + \nub{1}{%
        5 + \cdots + %
        95} + %
      97} + %
    99}%
  = 100 \times 49 \div 2%
  = 245%
$

\end{document}

Note
Ignore the mathematical error!

Load the tikz package instead of using the tikz class option. The class option not only loads the tikz package, but also places each tikzpicture on a new page. This is a problem if you want to reuse coordinates across different tikzpictures (via the tikzmark library)
% Source.
%     + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655445/6880

\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\unitht}{.8ex}
\newcommand{\nubpre}{A}

\newcommand{\nub}[2]{
  \tikzmark{a\nubpre#1}#2\tikzmark{b\nubpre#1}
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
                      overlay]
    \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1)  % Trait vertical à partir
          --++ (0,-#1*\unitht) % de la marque droite.
          -|                   % TikZ va tracer un "L"
          (pic cs:b\nubpre#1); % jusqu'à la marque de gauche.
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace{\unitht}%
}

\begin{document}
$%
  \nub{3}{%
    1 + \nub{2}{%
      3 + \nub{1}{%
        5 + \cdots + %
        95} + %
      97} + %
    99}%
  = 100 \times 49 \div 2%
  = 245%
$

\end{document}



This solves the problem, but this brings a new one. See this new question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730029/standalone-eats-my-extra-tikz-material .

Thanks for this.

@projetmbc You're welcome!
