Standalone eats my extra TikZ material
The following code doesn't take care of the extra matrerials decorating the equation. Is there a way to fix it?
% Source.
%     + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655445/6880
\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass{article} % To see the good output.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\unitht}{.8ex}
\newcommand{\nubpre}{A}

\newcommand{\nub}[2]{
  \tikzmark{a\nubpre#1}#2\tikzmark{b\nubpre#1}
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
                      overlay]
    \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1)  % Trait vertical à partir
          --++ (0,-#1*\unitht) % de la marque droite.
          -|                   % TikZ va tracer un "L"
          (pic cs:b\nubpre#1); % jusqu'à la marque de gauche.
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace{\unitht}%
}

\begin{document}

$%
  \nub{3}{%
    1 + \nub{2}{%
      3 + \nub{1}{%
        5 + \cdots + %
        95} + %
      97} + %
    99}%
  = 100 \times 49 \div 2%
  = 245%
$

\end{document}

Note
Ignore the mathematical error!

add a margin like I did in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730027/36296 :)

You realise that the maths you're showing is wrong, right? \sum_{x=1}^n x is n * (n-1) / 2, so in this case 4950 (the three pairs you're showing alone are 300 and hence bigger than 245).

You're specifying your tikzpicture as overlay hence it doesn't take up any space. How should standalone know its size?

Thanks for the clarification.

The math example will be corrected. I was focused on the use of standalone. ;-)

Slightly off topic but does this need TikZ if there's \underbracket? A bit more on topic: remember picture doesn't require overlay. Wouldn't it make more sense if the bracket would point directly at the numbers?

@Qrrbrbirlbel underbracket can't be used directly here, as the vertical lines won't start from the numbers. For TikZ and overlay, thanks for the info.

@Qrrbrbirlbel For brackets pointing to numbers, I really like the original layout. It's just a matter of taste :-)

You can replace overlay with \llap.
\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass{article} % To see the good output.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\unitht}{.8ex}
\newcommand{\nubpre}{A}

\newcommand{\nub}[2]{
  \tikzmark{a\nubpre#1}#2\tikzmark{b\nubpre#1}
  %
  \llap{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
    \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1)  % Trait vertical à partir
          --++ (0,-#1*\unitht) % de la marque droite.
          -|                   % TikZ va tracer un "L"
          (pic cs:b\nubpre#1); % jusqu'à la marque de gauche.
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
  %\vspace{\unitht}% horizontal mode
}

\begin{document}

$%
  \nub{3}{%
    1 + \nub{2}{%
      3 + \nub{1}{%
        5 + \cdots + %
        95} + %
      97} + %
    99}%
  = 100 \times 49 \div 2%
  = 245%
$

\end{document}


The advantage of this solution is that there is no need to adjust margins manually.

Removing overlay when TikZ draws outside its box isn't a good idea. Replacing it by \llap (which is sort of a horizontal overlay) doesn't quite work - there's an offset for each successive compilation that never settles down.

I don't see it.  But as it turns out, you don't need [remember picture] for tikzmarks.

Here is a good setting.
% Source.
%     + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655445/6880

\documentclass[border={3pt 12pt 3pt 3pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\unitht}{.8ex}
\newcommand{\nubpre}{A}

\newcommand{\nub}[2]{
  \tikzmark{a\nubpre#1}#2\tikzmark{b\nubpre#1}
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
                      overlay]
    \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1)  % Trait vertical à partir
          --++ (0,-#1*\unitht) % de la marque droite.
          -|                   % TikZ va tracer un "L"
          (pic cs:b\nubpre#1); % jusqu'à la marque de gauche.
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace{\unitht}%
}

\begin{document}

$%
  \nub{3}{%
    1 + \nub{2}{%
      3 + \nub{1}{%
        5 + \cdots + %
        95} + %
      97} + %
    99}%
  = 100 \times 49 \div 2%
  = 245%
$

\end{document}


Note
We can use negative border lengths. Here is a concrete example of use.
\documentclass[border={-63pt -17pt -7pt 3pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{adigraph}

\begin{document}

\NewAdigraph{automata}{
    s: 0, 0 ;
    t: 2, 1 ;
}{
    s, s: 3 ; 
    s, t: 2 ;
    t, s: 5 ;
}

\automata{}

\end{document}


Maybe do an alternative that is south of the nodes.

Can you explain a little more your idea?

Instead of the marker starting slightly to the left of the number, you can have it start at the center. Maybe even drop some arrows, why not :)

I really like this layout. It's just a matter of taste :-)

Removing the overlay options messes up how TikZ draws outside of its containing box. This causes issues as detailed at `latexmk` finds a "too many" compilation on one file
A better option is to ensure that TeX knows how much space to leave for the TikZ code, but still retaining the flexibility of TikZ to draw outside its containing box. Since you already do the necessary calculations, simply adding in a strut of the right height will do.
% Source.
%     + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655445/6880
\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass{article} % To see the good output.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\unitht}{.8ex}
\newcommand{\nubpre}{A}

\newcommand{\nub}[2]{
  \tikzmark{a\nubpre#1}#2\tikzmark{b\nubpre#1}
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
                      overlay]
    \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1)  % Trait vertical à partir
          --++ (0,-#1*\unitht) % de la marque droite.
          -|                   % TikZ va tracer un "L"
          (pic cs:b\nubpre#1); % jusqu'à la marque de gauche.
  \end{tikzpicture}%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline={(0,0)}] {\path (0,\nubvoffset*\unitht);}%
}

\begin{document}

$%
  \nub{3}{%
    1 + \nub{2}{%
      3 + \nub{1}{%
        5 + \cdots + %
        95} + %
      97} + %
    99}%
  = 100 \times 49 \div 2%
  = 245%
$

\end{document}

For a more complex case, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722197/86
